# Apache Drill : How to Query a Parquet file and output the result into a CSV file

Tags: csv, parquet, apache-drill

Here is a situation I am facing.

Environment : Desktop 
OS : Windows 7
Installed Apache Drill

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111
sqlline.bat -u "jdbc:drill:zk=local"
```

Got the Drill prompt

```
0: jdbc:drill:zk=local> !set outputformat csv
0: jdbc:drill:zk=local> !record "C:\Input\CSV\test_CSV.csv"
0: jdbc:drill:zk=local> select * from dfs.`C:\Input\CSV\test_Parquet.parquet` limit 1;
0: jdbc:drill:zk=local> !record
```

Output

```
Saving all output to "C:\Input\CSV\test_CSV.csv". Enter "record" with no arguments to stop it.
'field1','field2','field3','field4','field5','field6'
'B','9876','54321','123','KOHL'S CORPORATION, MEN','BOOK'
```

What I would like:

Values to be enclosed in double-quotes as opposed to single-quote

Tried !set outputformat txt as well even then the values are in double-quotes

I read that there are other ways to convert parquet file to csv, but curious to know how to do this using Apache drill.

Comment: so, _all_ of the values need to have double quotes around them?

Answer (score 1):

Apache Drill can create csv files using CTAS command [1]. Default output format is parquet so you would have to change it using `store.format` session option [2] but I doubt it would help to solve your issue with double-quotes.

[1] https://drill.apache.org/docs/create-table-as-ctas/

[2] https://drill.apache.org/docs/create-table-as-ctas/#alter-session-command

Answer (score 1):

To store data in double quotes using SqlLine you need to indicate csv quote character before doing recording:

```
!set csvquotecharacter '"'
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this.

Comment: Gives me an exception

0: jdbc:drill:zk=local> !set csvquotecharacter '"'
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
        at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1967)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.dequote(SqlLine.java:1270)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.split(SqlLine.java:1283)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.split(SqlLine.java:1102)
        at sqlline.AbstractCommandHandler.matches(AbstractCommandHandler.java:65)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.dispatch(SqlLine.java:725)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.begin(SqlLine.java:621)
...

Comment: Looks like it's a bug in SqlLine. Apache Drill 1.14.0 does not use the latest version of SqlLine but Apache Drill 1.15.0 will. You can build Apache Drill from master (1.15.0-SNAPSHOT) which is using latest SqlLine 1.5.0 version.

Comment: Yes, we have Drill 1.12.0 installed. I will upgrade to 1.15 and hopefully get it to work.

Comment: Apache Drill 1.15 release is planned in the end of November. Meanwhile, you can build SNAPSHOT version from the source.

Comment: We're not allowed to use SNAPSHOTs (workplace limitations :( ). I will wait for the release.

Comment: I installed latest SNAPSHOT today, building latest master version from Github, updated up to Nov 5, 2018, and despite using `!set csvquotecharacter '"'` doesn't throw any error, the CSV output still parsed without the quotes

Comment:  I reported the `csvquotecharacter` error here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-6840

Comment: Explained in Jira how to output quoted csv via SqlLine.